# htaccess rewrite causing problems for header in MVC

Tags: .htaccess

I've written an MVC controller that routes everything through the index file as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?(.*)?$ index.php?controller=$1&path=$2 [NC,L]
```

However, this causes a problem because when I want to include files in the header it cannot access them:

```
<link href=\"../css/bootstrap.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
```

How do I solve this problem? Can I prevent this htaccess rule from applying to certain folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude all real files and folders from the rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # your rule:
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?(.*)?$ index.php?controller=$1&path=$2 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```